# Rails: multiple REST actions in a single view ('new' and 'index')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I'm a beginner with Ruby on Rails plagued by a seemingly simple task; I haven't been able to find an answer that lines up with my goal, so here I am.

The page I'm working on is for 'Journal Entries.' There are two sections on this page: the left half is a form for creating a new journal post, and the right half is a list of all posts the user has written. In Rails, I set up a scaffolding with 'JournalEntriesController' and related views. The RESTful routes that were created work as expected: I can go to *localhost:3000/journal_entries/new* and there's a form for creating a new journal entry, and I can go to *localhost:3000/journal_entries* to see all journal entries already created. Instead of going to these two separate pages, how can I put both actions on the same page, side by side?

Along the same lines: if I wanted a page to have four sections where the user could Create, Read, Update, and Destroy, how would I go about doing this?

I have a few theories on how I could do this, but seeing as I'm pretty new to Rails, I'm not sure if I'd be hacking it together. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: There's routes which generally connect to controller actions which in turn generally render views.  If I understand you right, you want a view display that has something like multiple panes.  However you decide to format that view in HTML (offhand, in Ruby you'd probably use partials for this), it wouldn't affect the routes. Short answer: use each of the RESTful routes to render the same multi-paned view (probably by having the various controller action methods invoke a common method that supports the common view).  The majority of your work may be getting the view working the way you want.

Comment: Also depending on how rich you want the screen interaction to be you may be looking at a fair amount of Javascript and just using the Ruby controllers to provide back JSON data as an API server.  Not completely sure what you have in mind, so that may not be necessary though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting confused by scaffolding.

First, make sure you understand the difference between GET actions and POST actions. The former ones should only ever show information (except for incidental info like log files); the latter can change the information but it is a good form to put a redirect to a GET action to safeguard against refresh spam. (Assuming you're not doing AJAX PUT/DELETE/...)

So you want a GET page that will show you a view with a form that will submit to `.../new`, and a list that will lead you to `.../edit`. In essence, just take your `.../` (list) action and add a form for `.../new` to it, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Alot of it depends on how you set up your app.  But you are in control of what you put in the view.  It sounds like you you just need put POST actions in one view to do all the things you mentioned.

For example.  On your index page (which is generally a list of objects) you could do the following:
CREATE: add a link that opens a form for add a form that posts to journal_entries#create
READ: make each list item link to journal_entries#show for the appropriate object
UPDATE: add a link to each list item that opens a form that will post to journal_entries#update
DESTROY: add a link to each list item that posts to journal_entries#destroy